# C: listen() API returning -1

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I'm using below code to create a server program in c. The code is taken from [here](http://www.programminglogic.com/example-of-client-server-program-in-c-using-sockets-and-tcp/)

```
#include <Winsock.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
  int welcomeSocket, newSocket;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;

  /*---- Create the socket. The three arguments are: ----*/
  /* 1) Internet domain 2) Stream socket 3) Default protocol (TCP in this case) */
  welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /*---- Configure settings of the server address struct ----*/
  /* Address family = Internet */
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(7891);
  /* Set IP address to localhost */
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Bind the address struct to the socket ----*/
  bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  /*---- Listen on the socket, with 5 max connection requests queued ----*/
  if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0)
    printf("Listening\n");
  else
    printf("Error %d\n",listen(welcomeSocket,5));

  /*---- Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
  newSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);

  /*---- Send message to the socket of the incoming connection ----*/
  strcpy(buffer,"Hello World\n");
  send(newSocket,buffer,13,0);
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

I've changed the code little bit to make it work in dev-c but in the output it's printing error i.e it's executing the `else` condition. Anyone have any idea why? And how to debug this?

I've tried changing the port no. It didn't work.

Comment: It's helpful to look up the error number using `net helpmsg` on the command line. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490705.aspx

Comment: 1) check the returned value from socket() and bind()  and send() to assure the operations were successful  2) when outputing a message at a reaction to an error, use 'perror()' so the OS/system message is also output.  3) the number of characters in 'buffer' will differ, depending on the underlying OS.  suggest: 'send(newSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);'   oops, your on windows,  then need to use getlasterror() and similar statements rather than perror()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows, you have to initialize the networking subsystem first by calling [WSAStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), before you can make any calls to socket/network-related functions.

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int wsaRc = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (wsaRc != 0) {
   fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", wsaRc);
   return 1;
}

/* Socket related functions callable from here on */
```

The example-code you've linked was written for UNIX systems, which do not have that API-requirement.

---

Please note, that you also

> [...] must call the [WSACleanup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms741549%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function for every successful
>   time the WSAStartup function is called.

*(From the [WSAStartup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms742213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation).*

Comment: can you please explain what exactly this piece of code is doing?

Comment: I've added the MSDN documentation link for further clarification. From the MSDN: "The WSAStartup function initiates use of the Winsock DLL by a process." The Winsock DLL contains all socket related functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will go through the doc. :)